# Canvas remove linear gradient

Tags: canvas

I am using linear gradients to plot and re-plot hundreds (over time thousands) of icon shapes on a HTML canvas context each with its own unique linear gradient.

Is it possible to re-use a HTML canvas context linear gradient once created?

If so how do you change the x1,y1,x2,y2 and the stop colours?

Or can you remove the linear gradient from the context?

Or if neither of the above, does any other canvas function e.g. clearRect delete all linear gradients from the context within its boundaries?

Or if none of these, what is the performance penalty over a long period of time with thousands (hundreds of thousands?) of a context with linear gradient children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can reuse a CanvasGradient once created,

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var grads = [];
for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
  grads.push(ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,0));
}
grads.forEach(function(grad, i){
  var a = i * (360 / 20);
  grad.addColorStop(0, 'hsl(' + a + ',100%,50%)');
  grad.addColorStop(1, 'hsl(' + (a + 180) + ',100%,50%)');
  sel.appendChild(new Option("gradient " + i, i));
});

sel.onchange = function(){
  ctx.fillStyle = grads[+this.value];
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
};
sel.onchange();
```

```html
<select id="sel"></select><br>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

But no, you can't modify its inner properties set at creation. The only thing you can do with it is to add new color stops.

What can be done though is to change the transformation matrix of your context, this will also influence your gradients:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
gradWidth = 50, gradHeight = 50,
// a diagonal
grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, gradWidth, gradHeight),
angle = 0,x=150,y=40;
grad.addColorStop(0, 'red');
grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'blue');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'green');
ctx.fillStyle = grad;

function draw(){
  angle += Math.PI / 90;
  if(cb.checked){
    x += Math.cos(angle)*2;
    y += Math.sin(angle);
   }
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  ctx.translate(x + gradWidth/2, y + gradHeight/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(-gradWidth/2, -gradHeight/2);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<label>move on X/Y axes<input type="checkbox" id="cb"></label>
```

But this implies that all your other drawings will also follow this transformation...

So one way to move only the gradient is by using compositing, by first drawing your gradient across the whole canvas, and then draw only your shape, with the `globalCompositionOperation` set to `'destination-in'`:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
gradWidth = 150,
gradHeight = 50,
grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, gradWidth, gradHeight),
maxSize = Math.max(c.width, c.height),
angle = 0,x=c.width/4,y=c.height/2;
grad.addColorStop(0, 'red');
grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'blue');
grad.addColorStop(1, 'green');


function draw(){
  angle += Math.PI / 90;
  if(cb.checked){
    x += Math.cos(angle)*2;
    y += Math.sin(angle);
   }
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
  ctx.translate(x+gradWidth/2, y+gradHeight/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(-gradWidth/2, -gradHeight/2);
  ctx.fillRect(-maxSize*2,-maxSize*2,maxSize*4,maxSize*4);
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(c.width/4,c.height/2,150,50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<label>move on X/Y axes<input type="checkbox" id="cb"></label>
```

So one could probably write some helper function that would handle the transformations in an handy way, but I am not sure if the benefits compared to redeclaring new gradients are worth it.

---

Now, I am not clear as if you really need to edit your gradient or not, and if the latter, one option that you might want to consider, is to create a sprite-sheet of your icons on an off-screen canvas, and then simply call `drawImage` whenever you need this icon:

```js
const iconWidth = 120;
let icons, points;
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
onload = e => {
  icons = initIcons();
  points = icons.map(_ => ({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    dirX: 0,
    dirY: 0
  }));
  setInterval(updatePoints, 1000);
  draw();
};

function initIcons() {
  const pathes = pathes_d.map(d => new Path2D(d)),
    offCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  offCanvas.width = 500;
  offCanvas.height = 500;
  const coords = [],
    offCtx = offCanvas.getContext('2d');

  pathes.concat(pathes.slice(), pathes.slice())
    .forEach(function(p, i) {
      const grad = offCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 120 / 0.2, 120 /0.2),
      rand = ~~(Math.random() * 360);
      grad.addColorStop(0, 'hsl(' +  rand  + ', 100%, 50%');
      grad.addColorStop(1, 'hsl(' + (rand + 180) % 360 + ', 100%, 50%');
      offCtx.fillStyle = grad;
      let w = Math.floor(offCanvas.width / iconWidth),
        a = i / w,
        y = Math.floor(a),
        x = Math.round((a - y) * w) * iconWidth;
      y *= iconWidth;
      offCtx.setTransform(0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, x, y);
      offCtx.fill(p);
      coords.push({
        x,
        y
      });
    });
  coords.canvas = offCanvas;
  return coords;
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  points.forEach((pt, i) => {
    pt.x += pt.dirX;
    pt.y += pt.dirY;
    if (pt.x + 60 >= c.width || pt.x <= 0) {
      pt.dirX *= -1;
      pt.x += pt.dirX;
    }
    if (pt.y + 60 >= c.height || pt.y <= 0) {
      pt.dirY *= -1;
      pt.y += pt.dirY;
    }
    ctx.drawImage(icons.canvas, icons[i].x, icons[i].y, 120, 120, pt.x, pt.y, 60, 60);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function updatePoints() {
  points.forEach(pt => {
    pt.dirX += Math.random() - .5;
    pt.dirY += Math.random() - .5;
  });
}
const pathes_d = [
  "M59.9,62.2c0,6,3.7,12.6,11,20l161.7,161.7v196.5h-81.9c-4.4,0-8.3,1.6-11.5,4.9c-3.2,3.2-4.9,7.1-4.9,11.5  s1.6,8.3,4.9,11.5c3.2,3.2,7.1,4.9,11.5,4.9h229.3c4.4,0,8.3-1.6,11.5-4.9c3.2-3.2,4.9-7.1,4.9-11.5s-1.6-8.3-4.9-11.5  c-3.2-3.2-7.1-4.9-11.5-4.9h-81.9V243.9L459.9,82.2c7.3-7.3,11-14,11-20c0-3.9-1.5-7-4.6-9.3c-3.1-2.3-6.3-3.8-9.7-4.5  c-3.4-0.7-7.1-1-11-1H85.3c-3.9,0-7.6,0.3-11,1c-3.4,0.7-6.7,2.2-9.7,4.5C61.5,55.2,59.9,58.3,59.9,62.2z",
  "M101.7,71.9v286.6c0,8.5,2.9,16.1,8.7,22.8c5.8,6.7,13.1,11.8,22,15.5c8.9,3.7,17.7,6.4,26.5,8.2c8.8,1.8,17,2.7,24.7,2.7  c7.7,0,15.9-0.9,24.7-2.7c8.8-1.8,17.6-4.5,26.5-8.2c8.9-3.7,16.2-8.8,22-15.5c5.8-6.7,8.7-14.2,8.7-22.8s-2.9-16.1-8.7-22.8  c-5.8-6.7-13.1-11.8-22-15.5c-8.9-3.7-17.7-6.4-26.5-8.2c-8.8-1.8-17-2.7-24.7-2.7c-17.9,0-34.3,3.3-49.1,10V182l196.5,60.6V424  c0,8.5,2.9,16.1,8.7,22.8c5.8,6.7,13.1,11.8,22,15.5c8.9,3.7,17.7,6.4,26.5,8.2s17,2.7,24.7,2.7s15.9-0.9,24.7-2.7  s17.6-4.5,26.5-8.2c8.9-3.7,16.2-8.8,22-15.5c5.8-6.7,8.7-14.2,8.7-22.8s-2.9-16.1-8.7-22.8c-5.8-6.7-13.1-11.8-22-15.5  c-8.9-3.7-17.7-6.4-26.5-8.2c-8.8-1.8-17-2.7-24.7-2.7c-17.9,0-34.3,3.3-49.1,10V137.4c0-5.3-1.6-10.1-4.9-14.5  c-3.2-4.4-7.4-7.4-12.5-9.1L133.4,48.4c-2-0.7-4.4-1-7.2-1c-6.8,0-12.6,2.4-17.4,7.2C104,59.3,101.7,65.1,101.7,71.9z",
  "M199.9,227.5c0-31.6,11.2-58.6,33.6-81s49.4-33.6,81-33.6s58.6,11.2,81,33.6c22.4,22.4,33.6,49.4,33.6,81  s-11.2,58.6-33.6,81c-22.4,22.4-49.4,33.6-81,33.6s-58.6-11.2-81-33.6S199.9,259.1,199.9,227.5z M68.9,440.4c0,8.9,3.2,16.5,9.7,23  c6.5,6.5,14.2,9.7,23,9.7c9.2,0,16.9-3.2,23-9.7l87.8-87.5c30.5,21.2,64.6,31.7,102.1,31.7c24.4,0,47.7-4.7,70-14.2  c22.3-9.5,41.5-22.3,57.6-38.4c16.1-16.1,28.9-35.3,38.4-57.6c9.5-22.3,14.2-45.6,14.2-70s-4.7-47.7-14.2-70  c-9.5-22.3-22.3-41.5-38.4-57.6C426,83.8,406.8,71,384.5,61.6c-22.3-9.5-45.6-14.2-70-14.2c-24.4,0-47.7,4.7-70,14.2  S203.1,83.8,187,99.9s-28.9,35.3-38.4,57.6s-14.2,45.6-14.2,70c0,37.5,10.6,71.6,31.7,102.1l-87.8,87.8  C72.1,423.7,68.9,431.4,68.9,440.4z"
];
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks Kalido. Perhaps I did not explain. My canvas which has a map background is approx 1000 x1000 pixels. Each of the gradients are 30 x30 pixels. I have hundreds of gradients created wherever I need to plot an object on the map. Over time the objects move and I need to create a new gradient, even if the object has only moved 1 pixel to the right on the map. I used to plot images of external png files but this became unmanageable. I then moved to creating svgs dynamically and converting them to pngs but I could not get the latter to work on older versions of mobile safari. Thanks again.

Comment: @SteveBrooker then go with the last solution: generate sprite-sheets of your icons.

Comment: Kalido, Brilliant solution. I never knew that drawImage could draw anything other than an HTML Image onto the canvas. Individual offscreen canvas's for each icon, with one fixed gradient per icon are a superb solution. Thanks. I have accepted and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Why does your animation get faster?

Comment: @SteveBrooker it doesn't really, or at least not for all nodes and not constantly. I add a random value between -0.5 and 0.5 to every icon's `dirX` and `dirY`. So if it happens that this dirX or dirY is in the same sign than this random value, it will move faster. But this is all pseudo randomness.

Answer (score 0):

A linear/radial gradient is an Object typically applied as a `context.strokeStyle` or `context.fillStyle` value, so each time either of these `context` properties is reassigned the previous gradient (or color) is discarded.  What is needed here is a programmatic method for defining gradients which takes away the need for overly repetitious coding.

The following `makeGradient` function takes an Object of values as an argument and applies them to return the desired gradient type.  You may find something like this useful in your project.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), 
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function makeGradient(opts) {
    var grad = "linear" === opts.type ? 
        ctx.createLinearGradient(
            opts.dims.startX, opts.dims.startY, 
            opts.dims.endX, opts.dims.endY
        ) : ctx.createRadialGradient(
            opts.dims.startX, opts.dims.startY, 
            opts.dims.startR, opts.dims.endX, 
            opts.dims.endY, opts.dims.endR
        );
    opts.stops.forEach(function(n) {
        grad.addColorStop(n.stop, n.color);
    }); 
    return grad;
}

var options = {
    type: "linear",
    dims: {
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0,
        endX: 100,
        endY: 100
    },
    stops: [ 
        { stop: 0, color: "#F00" }, 
        { stop: .5, color: "#FF0" },
        { stop: 1, color: "#00F" }
    ]
};

ctx.fillStyle = makeGradient( options ), 
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Now the `options` Object can be amended/updated before being applied once more.  E.G...

```
options.type = "radial";
options.dims = {
    startX: 160,
    startY: 50,
    startR: 2,
    endX: 160,
    endY: 50,
    endR: 50
};

ctx.fillStyle = makeGradient( options )
ctx.fillRect(110, 0, 100, 100);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/gyyvjLr3/)

I hope this may be of some use.  ;)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have a similar function already (not perhaps quite as efficient as yours). My real worry is about the performance of canvas with hundreds/thousands of linear gradients still applied to it. Perhaps I did not explain. My canvas which has a map background is approx 1000 x1000 pixels. Each of the gradients are 30 x30 pixels. I have hundreds of gradients created wherever I need to plot an object on the map. Over time the objects move and I need to create a new gradient, even if the object has only moved 1 pixel to the right on the map.

Comment: @SteveBrooker No probs.  It's a knotty one for sure.  Good luck and report back if you find an elegant solution.  :)