# Referring to created canvas element

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following javascript code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("cvn");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 0);

gradient.addColorStop(0, "#00FF00");
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "black");
```

and would like to refer to the colorstops created later in the code. How would I do that?

I'd like to use it as such:

```
firstColorStop.setAttribute('offset', xyz);
```

Comment: Apparently, you dont. the CanvasGradient interface only exposes a method for setting a stop. Retrieval/modification are not facilitated. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient and here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvasgradient

Comment: That sucks. Any workarounds?

Comment: I guess since you've got to redraw to show any changes, you could keep 'cache' colourStop objects of your own design, then use them to create an actual colour stop right before drawing. A bit ugly, but easy enough.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494481/canvas-remove-linear-gradient/47507475#47507475

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables and just draw the canvas again.

How about something like this:

```html
<canvas id="cvn"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("cvn");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 300
  var blueStop = 1
  var color = "white"

  function drawStuff() {
    var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 240, 0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, color);
    gradient.addColorStop(blueStop, "blue");
    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(20,20, 240,60);

    var prop = canvas.width / 10
    for (var x = prop; x < canvas.width - prop * 1.5; x += prop)
      for (var y = prop; y < canvas.height; y += prop)
        ctx.rect(x, y, 9, 9);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  drawStuff();
  canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    blueStop = e.x/(canvas.width+10)
    color = (e.y > 100)? "red": "white"
    drawStuff();
  } 
</script>
```

Move the mouse over the canvas:

- the gradient stop color changes as your mouse moves in the X axis
- the color changes as your mouse to the bottom ( Y axis )

Comment: grr `beginPath` at the beginning of `drawStuff`.